# Allocating memory for structure element in heap?

Tags: c, pointers, malloc, structure

Allocating memory for structure element in heap but i am getting segmentation fault please help me to fix

```
#include<stdio.h>
 struct st
 {
      int i;
      int *p; 
      char ch;
 };
  int main()
{
    struct st *q;  // creating object pointer *q
    int i=89;
    q->p=malloc(10);
    printf("%d\n",*((q->p)-1)); // i m printing size allocated in heap?
    q->p=&i;                   // storing address i in structure element *p
    printf("%d\n",*(q->p));    // segmentation fault?
}
```

Comment: 1) `q` : uninitialize. 2) `*((q->p)-1)` : Outside the valid range access 3) `q->p=&i;` : memory leak.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY *((q->p)-1) : Outside the valid range access  ya i know but at this position no of byte  allocated by malloc is store and thats what i am trying to print.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`struct st *q;` declares a pointer to struct only. `q` pointing at unknown memory location. You need to allocate memory for `q` too otherwise it will invoke undefined behavior.

```
struct st *q = malloc(sizeof(struct st));
```

Also , `q->p=&i;` will cause memory leak.

Comment: @carrercarrer In your particular case, `q` does not need to be allocated on the heap.  You could do `struct st q; ... q.p = malloc(10);` if you wanted.

Comment: @carrercarrer My point is that `q` does not need to be a pointer in your example.  It can be a struct allocated on the stack.

Answer (score 0):

to determine which line of code segfaults your program one of the most easiest tricks is to printf("something distingishable") after a suspicous line.

By doing so, you would have found out, that the first access to q will fail.